# Where can I find bjam in the Cygwin Boost packages?

Tags: python, c++, boost, cygwin

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/hello.html), which suggests I use `bjam` to call C++ code from python.  I am using Cygwin on Windows 10 and have installed all of the Boost library packages.  I still can't find it anywhere in the installation.  I went to the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) page and am unable to find any mention of it. Do I need to install Boost from scratch just to get access to this tool? Part of me is convinced it has to be in the Cygwin installation somewhere, but I am unable to find it.  Thanks for any pointers/suggestions/answers you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the tutorial page it says :

> Before anything else, you should have the bjam executable in your boost directory or somewhere in your path such that bjam can be executed in the command line. Pre-built Boost.Jam executables are available for most platforms. The complete list of Bjam executables can be found here.

Where the link point to source forge where you can download the last version of bjam : https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-jam/3.1.18/

If you already have it on your computer from previous boost installations, just add it into your environnement path variable.

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the correct answer, and just something of an annoyance that Cygwin's install doesn't include it in their distribution.  Thanks.